# How can I get webstorm to autocomplete directories for gulp.src()?

Tags: macos, gulp, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Sorry if this question is out of place since it's a tool question, but being a dev tool I hope this is the best place to ask it. (And google yielded no useful results)

Webstorm usually provides directory autocompletion for things like `<link>` and `<script>` HTML tags, as well as `require()` functions in javascript. (See image below)

[image]

However, when I try this using the `gulp.src()` function, I get nothing.
[image]

Any idea how I can fix this? I have the `gulp-definitelyTyped` JS library installed and the NodeJS Core modules enabled in the Settings -> Javascript and Libraries -> Node and NPM menu. I'm also running the latest webstorm version on OS X.

Comment: WebStorm can only provide path completion in specific expressions in JavaScript like require and import statement. Would recommend you to create a feature request about completion in Gulp file: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB